# Vue adding external .js scripts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import

I am trying to add GameSparks SDK to my Vue project but I am having a few issues.

When adding GameSparks to a normal webpage you do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gamesparks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gamesparks-functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hmac-sha256.js"></script>
```

Then you can run this in a javascript:

```
var gamesparks = new GameSparks();

function init() {
    gamesparks.initLive({
        key: gsKey,
        secret: gsSecret,
        //credential: gsCredentials,
        onNonce: onNonce,
        onInit: onInit,
        onMessage: onMessage,
        logger: console.log,
    });
}

function onNonce(nonce) {
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(nonce, gsSecret));
}

//Callback to handle when the SDK is initialized and ready to go
function onInit() {
    console.log("Initialised");
}

init();
```

Now! I am adding the 3 javascripts inside my main.js file like this:

```
import GS from './assets/gamesparks/gamesparks'
import GSfunc from './assets/gamesparks/gamesparks-functions'
import Sha256 from './assets/gamesparks/hmac-sha256'
```

But this gives me an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GameSparks is not defined
>           at eval (gamesparks-functions.js?7884:1)

My question is... How do I implement the scripts correctly inside vue?

Really hoping for some help her... I am going nuts :-/

Comment: are you using nuxtjs?

Comment: Maybe try to also tell Vue to use these. A.k.a. Vue.use(GS); under the import

Comment: @isebarn - Not using nuxtjs.

Comment: @Flink - Adding Vue.use(GS) does not solve the isse :-/

Comment: Did you use all 3?

Comment: @Flink - yes :-/